# How to configure Laravel mail.php to use built-in mail function?

Tags: php, laravel, email

I need to send an email via the `mail()` PHP function.
I've read somewhere that I have to change `driver` parameter in `config/mail.php` to `sendmail`.

By default, it looks like this:

```
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
```

Now, it looks like this:

```
'driver' => 'sendmail',
```

Also tried this:

```
'driver' => 'mail',
```

But still, the `mail()` function doesn't work. What do I need to change?

Answer (score -32, accepted):

You can set your mail configuration `.env` file like

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=youremail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD="password"
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

also set configuration in config/mail.php like:

`'from' => ['address' => 'youremail@gmail.com', 'name' => 'Test'],`

then you can clear the cache:

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan cache:clear
```

Comment: These are not the correct settings for using PHP's mail() function. That function does not need username and email. These settings are used if you want to send the emails from another server like Gmail.

Comment: @wmacYes- Thank you! I have exactly the same problem as the OP, it's unbelievable how much time I've wasted with this now, and how little information there is on this. **How do you use PHP's mail() function with Laravel 5.5**? Is it possible? *That* is the question. I keep getting told to change to `MAIL_DRIVER=smtp` and enter my gmail account credentials but I don't want that! I have downvoted this as it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Link to thread where I am essentially asking the same thing: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46550390/521392

Comment: I had everything set up with my own mailserver (using smtp) and it wasn't working. Until I set `MAIL_ENCRYPTION`'s value to `tls` instead of the default value `null`...

Comment: this is not for php's sendmail configuration. it's an SMTP.

Comment: This may solve the problem, but is a false answer to the question because this way Laravel will not use php's built-in mail function as was asked.

Comment: This answer should not have been accepted. It is not a correct answer to this question, it's misleading.

Answer (score 69):

To do the same as mail() PHP function does, in most cases you should configure Laravel in the following way:

Use sendmail, at .env:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail
```

If you are using Larvel 7 or above

```
MAIL_MAILER=sendmail
```

<sup>Laravel 7 replaced `MAIL_DRIVER` by `MAIL_MAILER`</sup>

Host, user, password, port and encryption are not needed.

At this point, you may check if it already works, but sometimes the next step is also needed.

Set a new .env option in config/mail.php:

```
'sendmail' => env('MAIL_SENDMAIL', '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs')
```

Set the sendmail path in .env. You can check `sendmail_path` at phpinfo(), but it's usually this one:

```
MAIL_SENDMAIL='/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i'
```

Comment: This, here, is the correct answer. Especially that tidbit about setting the options to "sendmail -t -i" in my case. I hate to have to use this basic php mail function but in one of my projects I'm forced to... Thank you.

Comment: needs to be `'sendmail' => env('MAIL_SENDMAIL', '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs'),` in `config/mail.php` if you're going to edit it there. Don't forget the quotes and final comma

Comment: Oh! Thanks Chris, I've just fixed it in my answer.

Comment: Note that the `sendmail`driver requires that PHP's `proc_open()` function is not disabled for security reasons using `disabled_functions` in ´php.ini`.

Comment: For Laravel 7 and up, use `MAIL_MAILER=sendmail`

Comment: Have anyone a solution for using sendmail on windows machines?

Comment: Connection to localhost:25 Timed Out

Comment: confirming my `sendmail_path` in phpinfo was the solution for me. should be '/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i' instead of '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs'. Thanks @MaxOriola

Answer (score 29):

To use the email server running on `localhost`, your `.env` file should look like this (The PHP `mail` function doesn't need a username or a password)

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=localhost
MAIL_PORT=25
MAIL_USERNAME=
MAIL_PASSWORD=
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

Then, update the configuration cache:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Comment: Thank you very very much, friend!!! I have searched this answer so long time and this is bad, that laravel official documentation doesn't give this info. You are best, @lbel!

Comment: Thank you, just like @Vaha I couldn't find this anywhere. I've been searching for hours and nowhere is it said you should use it like this.

Comment: The php artisan config:cache part is vital, don't forget it as I did!

Comment: `php artisan config:clear` is the actual command that should be run I think

Comment: For a localhost you can just setup like this `MAIL_DRIVER=log` and it will print all mail in the log file. Very useful!

Comment: Note that from Laravel 7, use `MAIL_MAILER` in place of `MAIL_DRIVER`

Comment: username and passwords what we will add here is they will be empty?
by same above settings, it gives me a success message but email doesn't receive

Comment: Beautiful! this is a very useful and practical answer for testing and using in small projects.

Answer (score -3):

You have to set your mail Configuration in  .env file. Here you have to set all your mail driver and all details. Plase see this documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/mail

Comment: The link you posted explains how to configure a bunch of API drivers, but it doesn't explain how to configure sendmail, which is likely the reason OP posted this question.