# Laravel 5.5 error when trying to send mail using PHP's mail(): Expected response code 250 but got code "550"

Tags: php, laravel, email

I have upgraded a site to Laravel 5.5 and suddenly I can no longer send mail, as it gives me the following error:

> production.ERROR: Expected response code 250 but got code "550", with
>   message "550-Not authenticated, please enable SMTP Authentication in
>   email software and 550 check login credentials

I have no idea why it is trying to use SMTP when I have specified mail in my `.env`, which it seemingly ignores:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mail
MAIL_HOST=
MAIL_PORT=25
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

This is a completely fresh installation of Laravel 5.5. I have run `composer dumpautoload` and `artisan cache:clear`.

Help?

**EDIT:**

A simple PHP file with the following code works fine:

```
$to      = 'my_email_address@hotmail.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

exit();
```

Comment: what is your mail driver?

Comment: Mail is using SMTP. It's supposed to, as that's the Send Mail Transfer Protocol, which is on port 25. The only difference is that the `mail` driver uses PHP's `mail()` function. Make sure that it's connecting to localhost, if that's who you're attempting to send through, and make sure that the `config/mail.php` is getting your environment variables.

Comment: remove null for username and password

Comment: Does the raw `mail()` command work if you use it in a test PHP file or in `php artisan tinker` or something?

Comment: @ceejayoz Yes, it does- see edit.

Comment: Agree with @Disfigure, thank you for your answer. For me MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=localhost
MAIL_PORT=25
MAIL_USERNAME=
MAIL_PASSWORD=
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Swiftmailer 6.0 does not support the mail driver anymore**

With laravel, you also updated swiftmailer, and thus, the mail driver does not work anymore.

[Here is the swiftmailer commit that removed the mail driver in 6.0.](https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/commit/b0bcf96b1f290bd6d7bbe7bf8ab83f0be1b632b1#diff-f8bfbeb2220b9d0bd022da9deeea890a)

[It was deprecated since Swiftmailer 5.4.5 with this commit.](https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/commit/905b0bca8acf359dad3dfc2bc298c56de922cd57#diff-f8bfbeb2220b9d0bd022da9deeea890a)

[Here is a long discussion about why it was removed,](https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/issues/866) where
[the most useful comment](https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/issues/866#issuecomment-289291228) says that:

**PHP's `mail()` function is insecure**

The fifth parameter can be exploited to execute arbitrary code on most Linux systems. This is mainly because PHP incorrectly escapes shell arguments. You can read the full explanation in ["Why mail() is dangerous in PHP" by RIPS](https://blog.ripstech.com/2017/why-mail-is-dangerous-in-php/).

A couple of applications had security issues because of that, including Roundcube webmailer, MediaWiki, PHPMailer, ZendFramework, SquirrelMail and Swiftmailer. *And your app.* So be thankful that it got removed and use SMTP instead. You can usually simply use your local mail server using:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=localhost
MAIL_PORT=25
MAIL_USERNAME=
MAIL_PASSWORD=
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

(You may need to use `tls` encryption if your server does not accept local unencrypted mail.)

**Laravel**

The main issue with Laravel is that its documentation still mentions the mail driver [in the Laravel 5.7 documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/mail) and did only mention in their [upgrade notes for 5.5](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/upgrade) that swiftmailer 6.0 is required, but not that this means you cannot use the mail driver anymore.

Comment: You get the points. This was the answer that eluded me at the time. Shame you weren't around last year when I asked this, I seem to remember this being a particularly frustrating day :D

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, I have faced this error couple of days back and it turns out to be a problem of authentication error. This error itself clears the question it's an error that appears when credentials are not valid and in your case you haven't specified the credentials also you specified your `MAIL_DRIVER = mail` `mail` uses php's mail function whereas laravel itself ships with it's own mail mechanism I really recommend you to use that.

The geniune `.env` for mail will look like this ( I've used mail functionality using gmail)

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST= smtp@gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=25/587/465/2525 (any one)
MAIL_USERNAME=youremail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=your app password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

For App Password visit [here](https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords)

If you have looked into default `.env` file you can see something like this it is served with [mailtrap.io](https://mailtrap.io/) which recommend you for testing purpose specifically for local environemnt.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST= smtp@mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=dfj233ddfk3 // you will get this as you signup for mailtrap
MAIL_PASSWORD=your_mailtrap_password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

**UPDATE 1**

If you need to go on with `PHP's mail()` you need to install postfix or sendbox to send mails for this [follow these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47609/how-to-have-my-php-send-mail/47618#47618) alternatively I guess check [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43525560/how-to-configure-laravel-mail-php-to-use-usuall-mail-function) I think this might help you

Comment: I don't get it. I've used exactly the .env configuration as per my OP in other sites running Laravel 5.2 and it's worked fine. Why do you say `MAIL_DRIVER = mail` is wrong?

Comment: mail uses php's mail. if you are fully using laravel I really recommend laravel's approach of using smtp try my solution you will get rid of this error

Comment: So I am now forced to send emails through a gmail, or some other email provider, account?

Comment: if you are using gmail's smtp which is smtp@gmail.com then you will need to use gmail account for that if you want your own domain like example@domain.com then you need to have your own smtp and then in env it will look like this smtp@domain.com followed by it's email address and password  I don't know much about how to get your own smtp so I can't help in how to get your smtp stuff.

Comment: maybe you will get smtp from host provider when you get your domain

Comment: Thanks for your help, and if necessary I will use my own SMTP server as you suggest, just to get around this stupid problem. But I'm still not really understanding, and am annoyed that I now have this extra hassle when in the in past I could easily just leave out authentication and use native mail function. Do I understand that this is simply no longer possible with Laravel 5.5- is that what you're saying? This is not explicity mentioned in the docs, in fact it still states "*drivers for SMTP, Mailgun ... PHP's mail function*" https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mail

Comment: I don't feel my question has been answered: Why is my .env file being ignored? What is wrong with `MAIL_DRIVER=mail`? Why is Laravel ignoring this, instead trying to use SMTP, and then crying that I haven't specified username and password?

Comment: No you can use mail too but you need to check you are getting your credentials right try to put your credentials into env file

Comment: OK. Sorry if these are stupid questions. And thank you again for your help. But... *what credentials*? PHP's mail function doesn't require any credentials, right? See the edit to the OP. No credentials there. And I still have a raft of websites running Laravel 5.2 whose .env files just look like the OP

Comment: for security laravel uses these credentials. Yes you are right in Laravel 5.2 you won't need these but afterwards you need these credentials as far as I know.

Comment: Thanks. If you can provide a link to the Laravel docs (or somewhere 'official') where this change is stated, and tell me *what credentials I'm supposed to supply here in order just to use the native PHP mail() function*, that will answer my question (and I'll mark your answer correct). Thanks

Comment: yeah I have added an alternative way to use mail() function in laravel you need to use your email id and password to send that email like we use in PHPMailer class check my answer I guess my effort will help you :)

Comment: We're going round in circles here. Thanks for the link to the other SO question- that is exactly my question (this could be marked as a duplicate, in fact). The accepted answer there doesn't answer the question though- See the comment underneath: "*These are not the correct settings for using PHP's mail() function. That function does not need username and email. These settings are used if you want to send the emails from another server like Gmail.*" <- EXACTLY!

Comment: OK bro no problem! I tried but looks like I'm short to help you happy coding :)

Comment: OK, thanks for your input anyway, appreciate your time.

Comment: Pleasure, if you find the solution then please post it back here it will enlighten my knowledge :)

Comment: Will do. I've also commented on the accepted answer on the post that you linked to, so we'll see if that brings in any wisdom! :)

Comment: I hope I could enlighten your knowledge with my new answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

**2021 Update**

For Laravel 7 and up, use `MAIL_MAILER=sendmail`