# Unable to resolve NULL driver for [Illuminate\Mail\TransportManager] Laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6, laravel-mail

I'm trying to send an email using a Laravel Mail, following everything on the documentation, below is my mail.php

```
'default' => env('MAIL_MAILER', 'smtp'),

'mailers' => [
    'smtp' => [
        'transport' => 'smtp',
        'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
        'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
        'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
        'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
        'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
        'timeout' => null,
    ],

    'ses' => [
        'transport' => 'ses',
    ],

    'mailgun' => [
        'transport' => 'mailgun',
    ],

    'postmark' => [
        'transport' => 'postmark',
    ],

    'sendmail' => [
        'transport' => 'sendmail',
        'path' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
    ],

    'log' => [
        'transport' => 'log',
        'channel' => env('MAIL_LOG_CHANNEL'),
    ],

    'array' => [
        'transport' => 'array',
    ],
],
```

and tried just using the php mail by setting up on .env mail part to NULL

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=localhost
MAIL_PORT=1025
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=myemail@domain.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

and tried to send

```
Mail::to('drako@domain.com')
->bcc( app('config')->get('mail')['bcc'])
->send(new Get_a_quote($data));

if(count(Mail::failures()) > 0){
    return false;
}else{
    return true;
}
```

but my attempt returns an error

> Unable to resolve NULL driver for [Illuminate\Mail\TransportManager].

any help, ideas is greatly appreciated.

Comment: In your env these fields are required `MAIL_USERNAME`,
`MAIL_PASSWORD`,
`MAIL_ENCRYPTION`

Comment: @STA hello, I intend to use the built in php mail instead, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43525560/how-to-configure-laravel-mail-php-to-use-built-in-mail-function tried on my other laravel project, its working.

Comment: Change `MAIL_DRIVER=smtp` to `MAIL_DRIVER=mailgun` and try again

Comment: @STA i don't understand, im not using mailgun at all.

Comment: Did you try with `sendmail`?

Comment: @STA not sure how to do that.

Comment: @STA i just want to use the built in php mail

Comment: `MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail` documentation here https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/mail#introduction

Comment: @STA thanks but unfortunately theres no details there on how to configure it. im new to it

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the `MAIL_DRIVER` with `MAIL_MAILER` in your *.env* file.